# Unable to inject custom filter while performing integration testing using Spring boot test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, integration-testing, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

I have POST method in spring controller and I am trying to run test method on the controller using Test Rest template exchange.

Controller.java

```
    @RequestMapping(path = "/rest/projects")
    @RestController
    public class Controller {
    public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Controller.class);
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;
    private MailsService mailsService;

    @Autowired
    public Controller(MailsService mailsService, JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        this.mailsService = mailsService;
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }

@PostMapping(value = "/{projectId}/mails/filter/{type}")
    public ListDto getMails(@PathVariable("type") String mailType, @PathVariable("projectId") String projectId,
        @RequestParam(value = "page_number", required = false) String pageNumber,
        @RequestParam(value = "page_size", required = false) String pageSize,
        @RequestParam(value = "search_query", required = false) String searchKeyword,
        @RequestParam(value = "sort", required = false) String sortBy,
        @RequestParam(value = "sort_direction", required = false) String sortDirection,
        @RequestBody MailSearchModel mailSearchModel) throws BackendError {
        //calls service 
    }
}
```

Here is my test method

ControllerTest.java

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
    public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mock;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Autowired
    private RequestHeaderFilter requestHeaderFilter;

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    TestRestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    //Here i am trying to load Filter class in setup method

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    mock = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac)
            .addFilter(requestHeaderFilter).build();
    }


    @Test
    public void singleFieldProjectFields() throws Exception {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MailSearchModel mailSearchModel = mapper.readValue(new File("./src/test/resources/SingleValueSchema.json"),
            MailSearchModel.class);
    LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> requestParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    requestParams.add("sort_direction", "DESC");
    requestParams.add("page_number", "1");
    requestParams.add("sort", "sentdate");
    requestParams.add("page_size", "100");

    HttpEntity<MailSearchModel> entity = new HttpEntity<MailSearchModel>(mailSearchModel, headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            createURLWithPort("/rest/projects/{projectId}/mails/filter/{type}"), HttpMethod.POST, entity,
            String.class,"1879053221","inbox",requestParams);

    String actual = response.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.LOCATION).get(0);

    assertTrue(actual.contains("/mails"));
}
```

Here is how my custom filter looks like

RequestHeaderFilter.java

```
    @WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/rest/*")
    @Order(1)
    public class RequestHeaderFilter implements Filter {
    private LocalizationHelper localizationHelper;
    private ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper;
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;
    private BabylonCookieProvider babylonCookieProvider;
    private BabylonSessionService babylonSessionService;

    @Autowired
    public RequestHeaderFilter(LocalizationHelper localizationHelper, ObjectMapper 
    jacksonObjectMapper,
    JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider, BabylonCookieProvider babylonCookieProvider, 
    BabylonSessionService babylonSessionService) {
    this.localizationHelper = localizationHelper;
    this.jacksonObjectMapper = jacksonObjectMapper;
    this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    this.babylonCookieProvider = babylonCookieProvider;
    this.babylonSessionService = babylonSessionService;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    // Do nothing
    }

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    // Add RequestId in request scope bean
    addRequestIdInSessionScope(httpRequest);

    // Check request authentication
    String auth = httpRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
    if (Utility.isNullOrEmpty(auth)) {
        ErrorDto errorDto = getErrorDto(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, JwtConstants.TOKEN_MISSING);
        postErrorResponse(httpResponse, errorDto);
    } else {
        auth = auth.replace(JwtConstants.TOKEN_TYPE_BEARER, "").trim();
        String tokenStatus = parseJweToken(auth);
        afterValidation(request, response, chain, auth, tokenStatus);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the Main class

MobileApplication.java

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @ServletComponentScan
    public class MobileApplication {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(MobileApplication.class, args);
       }
     }
```

While i try to run my test i am getting the following error

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.oracle.cegbu.aconex.filter.RequestHeaderFilter': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#6221ac7d' of type [com.oracle.cegbu.aconex.filter.RequestHeaderFilter] while setting bean property 'filter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6221ac7d' defined in file [/Users/sachinhr/Aconex/ora-acx-spring-bff/build/classes/java/main/com/oracle/cegbu/aconex/filter/RequestHeaderFilter.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 4; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'babylonSessionService' defined in file [/Users/sachinhr/Aconex/ora-acx-spring-bff/build/classes/java/main/com/oracle/cegbu/aconex/service/auth/BabylonSessionService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bffRestTemplate' defined in file [/Users/sachinhr/Aconex/ora-acx-spring-bff/build/classes/java/main/com/oracle/cegbu/aconex/common/delegate/BffRestTemplate.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'baseUrlProvider': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Circular placeholder reference 'instance' in property definitions
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:134) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:212) ~[spring-boot-2.5.9.jar:2.5.9]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:203) ~[spring-boot-2.5.9.jar:2.5.9]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:97) ~[spring-boot-2.5.9.jar:2.5.9]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.5.9.jar:2.5.9]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:260) ~[spring-boot-2.5.9.jar:2.5.9]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:234) ~[spring-boot-2.5.9.jar:2.5.9]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.5.9.jar:2.5.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5219) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.5.9.jar:2.5.9]
... 63 common frames omitted
```

Its not able to instantiate Filter class and failing.

Comment: Good, that you tried a test at least! Circular dependency:or eliminate or "workaround" ... start investigation at `babylonSessionService`

Comment: Do i need to add all dependent services for controller if i am using Test Rest template and Spring boot test annotation as i am doing integration testing. However i tried autowiring all dependent classes. Still same error